# How to implement Google Tag Manager across dozens of sites within the same network

Tags: google-tag-manager

We run a network of approx. 80 different sites (unique URLs) within our institutional enterprise network. These sites are separate and distinct, yet are all live within the same organization.

I have been rolling out GTM to each of the sites on a one-by-one GTM Container ID basis -- meaning each site is getting its own GTM Web Container.

I have seen other instances where similar "networks" utilize one GTM Container ID for all sties within their network.

Given my infancy level and experience with GTM, my question is "what is the proper way to implement GTM across multiple separate and distinct sites within the same common enterprise? Create a separate GTM Cid for each site or create 1 common GTM Cid for all sites?

What are the pros and cons to each of these approaches. Are there technical and/or performance issues with creating dozens, if not hundreds of tags and triggers in the implementation approach of a single GTM Cid?

Thank you for helping me understand the most effective way to implement GTM.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of to solve it effectively.

1. Use the same GTM container ID in all your pages. This way you only have to manage one container and all your changes will be live on all pages. However all pages should be exactly the same, when it comes to tracking. If there are differences, you will have to manage gigantic lookup table variables in GTM. For instance if you need to track GA pageviews in separate accounts you will need to lookup domain value and pass the correct UA-... ID value to track the data in the correct Google Analytics property.
2. You can use separate GTM container IDs and use one container as a reference. The reference container will need to be exported as JSON file. Now this setting can be imported in all other GTM containers. However you need to rename parts of the setup, so you cant just export and import the setup 1:1. Since also here, static variable values like UA-... IDs will be different in your setups.

Comment: Thank you @michaelsinner. I too, know of these 2 methods. I am currently using the 2nd method you describe. But I am wondering what most people doing and the implications of dozens/hundreds of triggers and tags in method 1. Does it have a noticeable impact of page load performance in anyway?